# Nullable reference types unexpected CS8629 Nullable value type may be null with temporary variables

Tags: c#, c#-8.0, nullable-reference-types

In a C# 8 project, I am using nullable reference types and am getting an unexpected (or at least, unexpected to me) CS8629 warning,

```
bool singleContent = x.DataInt != null;
bool multiContent = x.DataNvarchar != null;

if (singleContent && multiContent)
{
    throw new ArgumentException("Expected data to either associate a single content node or " +
        "multiple content nodes, but both are associated.");
}

if (singleContent)
{
    var copy = x.DataInt.Value; // CS8629 here
    newPropertyData.DataNvarchar = $"umb://{type.UdiType}/{Nodes[copy].UniqueId.ToString("N")}";
}
```

I've decided to use `GetValueOrDefault()` as a workaround, but I'd like to know how to prove to the compiler that `x.DataInt` can't be null if `singleContent` is checked.

Note that the type of `x.DataInt` is `int?`.

Comment: The "correct" workaround here would be to use the damnit operator -- `x.DataInt!.Value`

Comment: @canton7 So I see. How did I miss something called the damnit operator... damn. I guess my brain isn't braining very well this morning.

Comment: dotnetfiddle is up. Sometimes referred to as the "postfix operator"

Comment: I suspect if you changed the code to `if(x.DataInt!=null){...}` the warning would go away. The compiler can be excused in this case - some other code could easily change the value of `singleContent`.

Comment: This is a known limitation of the analysis. This is discussed in https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/issues/34800 (Nullable warning when tmp variable introduced)

Comment: @JulienCouvreur this should be posted as an answer, explaining that it's out of scope for C# 8. Lots of people are going to run into this problem in the next year. You may have to fluff up the answer a bit to avoid knee-jerk downvotes

Comment: @JulienCouvreur That's not exactly the same issue but I think it will fall under the same response though, that it requires deeper analysis support and is out of scope for C# 8.

Comment: I agree with @canton7, this is probably a good use case for the `!` operator. *However*, you need to be careful so that you don't accidentally overwrite the `singleContent` variable with a new value between the two current places you use it, because the `!` operator will not catch a change of intent.

Comment: @LasseVågsætherKarlsen Julien is one of the designers of nullable types. So whether the issue's wording matches or not, he's the best qualified to write a good answer to this question (nag nag)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is just a temporary answer until Julien Couvreur, one of the designers of nullable reference types posts the definitive answer (nagging). I'm posting this here because the question will be asked again once C# 8 is released.

As Julien answers in 3 Github issues [#34800](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/issues/34800) , [#37032](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/issues/37032) and [#36149](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/issues/36149) this is a known limitation of the C# 8 analyzer that's out of scope for C# 8.

This requires alias analysis which (just guessing here) means that the analyzer will be able to analyze aliased expressions, ie expressions whose results are "hidden" behind temporary variables (possibly parameters too?).

Perhaps we can ask him or Mads Torgersen online when .NET Core 3 is released during [.NET Conf 2019](https://www.dotnetconf.net/) about a release date (totally not nagging)

Comment: The reason I said in my comment that it's not exactly the same issue is that aliasing, which means you introduce another variable for the same thing, like `var x = y;`, is not the same as data dependencies, like `var x = y != null;`, which requires flow analysis. I could be wrong though, they could be considered the same, it's been a loong time since I looked at compiler design and its terminology. Either way, they both boil down to the same broad reason, code analysis isn't that sophisticated in C# 8 (yet).