# How to avoid irrelevant nullable warning (without explicit suppression)

Tags: c#, nullable, c#-8.0

Is there a way to make the analyzer understand that the variable `Bar` has a value for the following case?

```
#nullable enable 
class Foo {
   bool GenerateArray => Bar.HasValue;
   int? Bar { get; set; }
   void FooBar() {
     var data = (GenerateArray) ? new int[Bar.Value] : null;
   }
}
```

There is the warning "Nullable value type may be null." for `Bar.Value` but it obviously can't be.

I am aware of two ways to avoid the warning. Both have disadvantages:

1. Using `Bar.HasValue` directly instead of the property `GenerateArray`. However using `GenerateArray` improves readability.
2. Using `Bar!.Value` instead of `Bar.Value`. However, if someone changes the code, for instance, by making `GenerateArray` an auto-property in the future, the warning may become relevant again, but won't appear.

The problem here slightly differs from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57432944), where a local variable was used instead of a property. The accepted answer below works (as soon as C# 9 is released) for the property but not for the local variable, if I understand it correctly. Hence, the question is not a duplicate.

Comment: "but it obviously can't be." Are you sure about that? is it thread safe?

Comment: If I use Bar.HasValue directly instead of the property GenerateArray, the warning goes away, but in terms of thread safety nothing has changed. Hence, I would ignore this aspect.

Comment: Are you sure it improves readability? For me it doesn't. It adds one more hoop I have to jump through to see what the code is actually doing. Using Bar.HasValue seems much clearer to me.

Comment: I'm curious as to why you think `if (Bar.HasValue)` affects the readability. If anything, it's more explicit and anyone would know what's going on at first glance. Am I missing something?

Comment: Did you check this ?https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57432944/nullable-reference-types-unexpected-cs8629-nullable-value-type-may-be-null-with

Comment: @AhmedAbdelhameed For this small example you are right: There is not much improvement w.r.t. readability. However, this is not the purpose of it. In my code there are several places with similar patterns, where the usage of a flag with a good name in an if-condition is better readable then something like `variable.HasValue`.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Will be be able to use the `MemberNotNullWhen` attribute in C# 9 (currently in preview):

```
[MemberNotNullWhen(true, "Bar")]
bool GenerateArray => Bar.HasValue;
```

The relevant attribute types will exist in .Net 5:

```
namespace System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis
{
    [AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Method | AttributeTargets.Property, AllowMultiple = true)]
    public sealed class MemberNotNullAttribute : Attribute
    {
        public MemberNotNullAttribute(params string[] members) { }
        public MemberNotNullAttribute(string member) { }
    }
}

namespace System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis
{
    [AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Method | AttributeTargets.Property, AllowMultiple = true)]
    public sealed class MemberNotNullWhenAttribute : Attribute
    {
        public MemberNotNullWhenAttribute(bool when, params string[] members) { }
        public MemberNotNullWhenAttribute(bool when, string member) { }
    }
}
```

[Illustration on sharplab](https://sharplab.io/#v2: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)

Answer (score 0):

Following the link in the comment of mahesh_b I found [this roslyn issues](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/issues/36149) stating that, sadly, there is no other way  to avoid the warning in C# 8.0.