# Nullable Reference Types and HasValue-Style Properties

Tags: c#, properties, c#-8.0, nullable-reference-types

Let's say we have this simple `User` class that has an optional (nullable) property for a phone number:

```
public class User
{
    public string? PhoneNumber { get; private set; }
}
```

And then, in other classes, I need to use the phone number of a user, if it has one:

```
public static void Example(User user)
{
    if (!(user.PhoneNumber is null))
    {
        DoSomething(user.PhoneNumber);
    }
}
```

This works fine, but is not even close to the readability of having something like:

```
public class User
{
    public string? PhoneNumber { get; private set; }
    public bool HasPhoneNumber => !(PhoneNumber is null);
}
```

And then using it like so:

```
public static void Example(User user)
{
    if (user.HasPhoneNumber)
    {
        DoSomething(user.PhoneNumber);
    }
}
```

This worked fine until C# 8's null safety changes. Now, the code above triggers a CS8604. This, of course, is the expected behavior of the compiler, but I am still looking for a way to avoid having `is null` (or `!= null`) checks scattered all over the codebase. Is there a way to tell the compiler that a property is not null after a call to a method (or another property), similar to how the `[NotNullWhen]` attribute works for parameters?

Comment: Here's the pattern of "has value" for `string`: `PhoneNumber?.Length > 0`

Comment: @aepot my problem is not with the implementation of the property, but with the usage. I need a way to tell the compiler that when the `HasPhoneNumber` property is true, `PhoneNumber` is not null.

Comment: How can you tell the compiler the value state of runtime variable? Compiler doesn't deal with runtime values. Now you're telling the compiler that it is nullable with `?`. You can replace `string?` with `string`. Sorry, i'm noob and don't know any reasons for `string?` because regular `string` also can be `null`.

Comment: As a simple string, you can also test `if ([User].PhoneNumber is string s) { // non null, use s } else { // is null, complain because it's private set and you cannot add one }`

Comment: @GurGaller Please, check the next question: [How to avoid irrelevant nullable warning (without explicit suppression)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62676807/how-to-avoid-irrelevant-nullable-warning-without-explicit-suppression). I think that the problem is the same. A solution to the problem will be available in `C# 9`.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use an extension method like `IsNullOrEmpty()` or something like `HasValue`? You can use `string` rather than `string?` and checking `null` value will be like this:

```
public static void Example(User user)
{
    if (user.PhoneNumber.HasValue())
    {
        DoSomething(user.PhoneNumber);
    }
}
```

Comment: It's an improvement over using `!= null`, and this way I can decorate the extension method's parameter with a `[NotNullWhen(true)]` attribute, but it's still not as readable as my original solution of having a specialized property, in my opinion. It seems weird that there is no equivalent to it in the latest version of the language.